# Pullback and (co)equalizers as a universal cone definition

Tags: category-theory, definition, limits-colimits

$J$-shaped diagram in $\mathcal{C}$ is a functor $D: J\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$. Now, a limit of $D$ is a universal cone, which is an object $Y$ together with morphisms $f_i:Y\rightarrow D(X_i)$ for **all** objects $X_i \in \operatorname{obj}(J)$ (also all triangles must commute etc.)

Now, in the definition of pullback, we have three objects $A,B,C$ and morphisms $\pi_B : B\rightarrow C$ and $\pi_A : A\rightarrow C$. Pullback is then defined as a object $P$ together with $p_A : P\rightarrow A, p_B : P\rightarrow B$ satisfying the universal property (i.e. for any other $Y$ together with morphisms $q_A,q_B$ there is unique $\varphi$ s.t. $q_A = p_A \circ \varphi, q_B = p_B \circ \varphi$).

Sometimes this is also regarded as a limit of the pullback diagram. But hold on, shouldn't the limit have morphisms to all objects ? I.e. also to the object $C$? What is going on here?

I think simillar problem arises with (co)-equalizers. There we have two parallel morphisms $f,g : A\rightarrow B$ and equalizer is object $E$ with morphism $e:E\rightarrow A$ but nothing is said about morphism to the object $B$.
Same question arises.

EDIT: According to the comment the third morphism to the object $C$ is implicitly given by $\pi_A \circ p_A = \pi_B \circ p_B$. But consider additional cone $P$ together with morphisms $p_A, p_B$ and some $p_C$ different from $\pi_A \circ p_A$. The universal property assures existence of unique $\varphi$ s.t. $p_A = \varphi \circ p_A$ and $p_B = \varphi \circ p_B$ and $p_C = \varphi \circ \pi_A p_A$. The first two equations force $\varphi$ to be the identity, but  $p_C$ was chosen to be different from $\pi_A p_A$. This is weird.

Comment: The third map is implicitly given by $\pi_A p_A = \pi_B p_B : P \to C$.

Comment: But then, take as another cone the pullback $P$ together with $p_A, p_B$ and some other morphism $p_C : P\rightarrow C$ which is not $\pi_Ap_A=\pi_Bp_B$. There should be unique $\varphi$ s.t. $p_C\circ \varphi = \pi_A \pi_B$. But since this should factor through $p_B,p_A$ too, this forces $\varphi$ to be the identity morphism on $P$, which would then be $p_C = \pi_A p_A$ but I assumed this not to be the case.

Comment: You are stating the universal property of pullbacks wrong (in your second paragraph). A pullback is the universal $P$ with arrows $p_A$ and $p_B$ such that $\pi_A p_A = \pi_B p_B$. Three random maps $p_A$, $p_B$, $p_C$ do not constitute a cone over the relevant diagram unless $\pi_A p_A = p_C = \pi_B p_B$. This precisely the bit in your first paragraph which you kind of skip over ("also all triangles must commute etc.") but which is crucial in the definition of a cone. (Note that you are essentially giving the definition of a product, not a pullback, in your second paragraph.)

Comment: Aaaah, yeah. I see it now. So specifying $p_A$ (for example), then any $p_C$ must satisfy $p_C = \pi_B \circ p_B$.